# How to use kubectl cp to copy files from a pod's folder with space in its name

Tags: kubernetes, copy, kubectl, cp

I came accross an issue with the kubectl cp command. I tried to copy from the following folder by usingg the kubectl cp command, but to no avail: agent/workspace/Performance Testing/Nightly/GrafanaReporter/output/

Here is the entire cp command that failed:

```
kubectl cp devops/capru-nightly-5w74q-5c3nc:agent/workspace/Performance Testing/Nightly/GrafanaReporter/output/ .
```

Kubectl does not give any feedback about the success of the command, so I kept trying until I realised that the the root cause of the issue is the space in the name of the "Performance Testing" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around and I found that this issue can be solved by using "" around the path that contains the space.

Here is the command that runs perfectly:

```
kubectl cp "devops/capru-nightly-5w74q-5c3nc:agent/workspace/Performance Testing/Nightly/GrafanaReporter/output/" .
```